# Bold formatting fails to render when characters wrapped in asterisks are in the unicode character set and not in ASCII

Tags: bug

Bold formatting fails to render when characters wrapped in asterisks are in the unicode character set and not in ASCII

**y⁻¹**

```
**y⁻¹**
```

The compliment of the set of things represented by word y where y = "litter".

For use in a ven diagram for the words:

> - "trash"
> - "palanquin"
> - "litter"

Comment: Looks bold to me...

Answer (score 1):

It appears bold to me. For another test, here are some IPA characters: ɑæɛɪɔʊ **ɑæɛɪɔʊ**.

I suspect it's a font issue. Whatever font your system is using for bold text on this site may not include those particular characters.